# trying to encage getDate() inside a var

Tags: javascript, date, var, getdate

Someone could please help me understand why on Earth this is not working?

```js
    document.write('messing with the dates: <br>')
    var nowDate = new Date();
    var currentDay = nowDate.getDate();
    nowDate.setDate(currentDay + 1);
    document.write('if it\'s not inside a variable, it\'s nice and tidy: ' + nowDate.getDate() + '<br>');

    var tomorrow = (nowDate.setDate(currentDay + 1));
    document.write('but as soon as I put it inside a var, it becomes terrible: ' + tomorrow);

    document.write('and this is not even working' + tomorrow.getDate());
```

Comment: What "isn't working"? What are you expecting to happen? What actually happens?

Comment: `var tomorrow = (nowDate.setDate(currentDay + 1));` is not equivalent to `var tomorrow = nowDate.getDate()` why aren't you using the latter? it seems like that's what you want.

Comment: I'm not using getDate() because I already know the date, I want to modify the date instead.

Comment: This works brilliantly:
`nowDate.setDate(currentDay + 1);
document.write(nowDate.getDate());`

This doesn't:
`var tomorrow = nowDate.setDate(currentDay + 1);
document.write( tomorrow);`
This is the problem and I cannot understand why.

Answer (score 0):

`setDate` does two things, changes the Date Object itselfs, and returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC of the resulting date.

Which is the number you're getting on `tomorrow`

I guess you should use it like that to achive what you're trying to do:

```
var tomorrow = new Date((nowDate.setDate(currentDay + 1)))
```

Comment: `var tomorrow = nowDate.setDate(currentDay + 1);
 document.write(tomorrow);`
returns
`1448918139765 `
if I do `document.write(tomorrow.getDate());`
nothing happens. WHY??!

Comment: ok using `new Date()` works!! Thank you very much!!  
But now could someone explain me why  
`var tomorrow = nowDate.setDate(currentDay + 1);`  
is wrong and why you should instead write  
`var tomorrow = new Date((nowDate.setDate(currentDay + 1)));`

Comment: As i said, because `nowDate.setDate(currentDay + 1)` returns number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC - and that's what `tomorrow` gets